# sys.argv apparently doesn't work the way i think

Tags: python, input

so I have this exercise and the user has to choose the two indexes of the Fibonacci sequence, the beginning, and the end. The exercise demands that I use sys.arg for the user to enter the two indexes. Well, apparently I don't know yet how to use it. I would appreciate a little help.

```
 import sys
     print 'the beginning: ' sys.arg[1]
     print '\nthe end: ' sys.argv[2]

 def fib(n):
   if n < 2:
    return n
return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)

print map(fib, range(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you posted? Aside from the IndentationErrors? Please read [mcve]. Specifically, be specific about what the problem is. "Apparently I don't know yet how to use it" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Apparently `map` and `range` also don't work as you think

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's what you were looking for:

```
import sys

print 'the beginning: ' + sys.argv[1]
print 'the end: ' + sys.argv[2]

def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)

print map(fib, range(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])))
```